# Best practice javascript data formatting

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am fetching a list of users from the database table :

```
userid username created

1       xyz      1384875794
```

Where *created* is the UNIX time [using PHP time()] at which the user was created.

But in the browser while printing these users , i will be converting the php time into 
a readable format [eg. Nov 19 2013] using javascript .

Here comes my question :

Suppose if the javascript function format_time(time) converts the time into readable format .

Which of the following two ways is preferred

**First way :**

Use javascript inline like this

```
<table>
<?php foreach($users as $user) {
 <tr>
   <td> <?php echo $user['name']; ?> </td>
   <td> <script>format_time(<?php echo $user['created']; ?>)</script></td> 
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Here the format_time() will use document.write() to print the formatted time.

**Second way :**

Use javascript after DOM load

1. Get $users array from DB using ajax
2. Loop through the array and do innerHTML

I can even remove above ajax request by converting the php variable $users 
to a javascript by JSON encode/decode and repeat the above second step.

Comment: Can you convert the time before encoding it to JSON and sending it back to your Javascript? I personally hate everything Date and time methods have to offer in Javascript. Using PHP's date methods are way more sound.

Comment: You mean , convert the time in server side ? Yes i can do that, its just that i had already invested a lot of time in the javascript functions .

Comment: Reinventing the wheel, you mean? Date conversion is really simple. Wasting time creating new functions is not best-practice :-p Just go with the solid solution which doesn't needs hotfixing and debugging ;)

Comment: No, i am not, the date conversion is a one line code , but that function also include many other checks, like if the date is today , is the date from current month or from current year etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I suggest you process the issue format of time in `php`, then output the processed result:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($users as $user) {
 // format_time is a function to format time in php script
 $created = format_time($user['created']);?>
 <tr>
   <td> <?php echo $user['name']; ?> </td>
   <td> <script>format_time(<?php echo $created; ?>)</script></td> 
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

If you just want to output the $users object then use it in javascript, you can do it like below:

```
<?php
$users = array(array('name' => 'srain'));
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var users = " . json_encode($users) . ";</script>";
?>
```

Then you can access users in javascript.

Comment: Is there any advantage in processing the time in php compared to javascript ?

Comment: Yes, use `js` to process the time after load, the page may no display correctly at the first beginning. If process that in `php` then output it to page, the page will display the right content from the first beginning.

Comment: ok, i will then rewrite my functions in php